# How to add a downward force to an Instantiated prefab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get my prefabs to just fall at some speed.  Right now they get created and then gravity acts on it, so it starts off slow and then builds as it is in the air.  I want it to be a constant speed from the moment it is created.

I have tried doing an AddForce, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
void Wave1()
{
    Debug.Log("Wave1");
    delay = .5f;
    Instantiate(smallFlame, new Vector3(drop1, dropHeight, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(smallFlame, new Vector3(drop2, dropHeight, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(smallFlame, new Vector3(drop3, dropHeight, 0), Quaternion.identity);

    smallFlame.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, fallSpeed), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to their position in the update loop rather than using the physics engine.

```
void Update()
{
    transform.position += Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

This will move any object that it is attached to down at a constant rate. Put this in a script and add it to the prefab that you are instantiating.

Comment: They still have a slow to fast happening.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, you need to remove their ridgidbody in order to stop using the physics engine.

Comment: You will most likely have to multiply `Time.deltaTime` by some value in order to make the objects travel at the speed you want too.

Comment: @gjttt1 Do you know why the script of Tim Cooley does not work?

Comment: @tim Yeah, he was using a rigidbody which simulates realistic physics/Gravity. He wanted 'unrealistic' movement so adding to the position vector would suffice. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should set to zero the "Gravity Scale" of the RigitBody2D atached to the smallFlame. This should stop the acceleration.

To add moviment to them. Use [Rigitbody2D.velocity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html)